# R Aggregate and count of not null

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data table

```
PIECE   SAMPLE  QC_CODE
1       1       1
2       1       NA  
3       2       2
4       2       4
5       2       NA
6       3       6
7       3       3
8       3       NA
9       4       6
10      4       NA
```

and I would like to count the number of qc_code in each sample and return an output like this

```
SAMPLE    SAMPLE_SIZE    QC_CODE_COUNT
1         2              1
2         3              2
3         3              2
4         2              1
```

Where sample size is the count of pieces in each sample, and qc_code_count is the count of al qc_code that are no NA.

How would I go about this in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
     group_by(SAMPLE) %>% 
     summarise(SAMPLE_SIZE=n(), QC_CODE_UNIT= sum(!is.na(QC_CODE)))

 #   SAMPLE SAMPLE_SIZE QC_CODE_UNIT
 #1      1           2            1
 #2      2           3            2
 #3      3           3            2
 #4      4           2            1
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(SAMPLE_SIZE=.N, QC_CODE_UNIT=sum(!is.na(QC_CODE))), by=SAMPLE]
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
do.call(data.frame,aggregate(QC_CODE~SAMPLE, df1, na.action=NULL,
  FUN=function(x) c(SAMPLE_SIZE=length(x), QC_CODE_UNIT= sum(!is.na(x)))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PIECE = 1:10, SAMPLE = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), QC_CODE = c(1L, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 6L, 3L, NA, 
6L, NA)), .Names = c("PIECE", "SAMPLE", "QC_CODE"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```